# Turn close proximity elements of a 2d NumPy array into that proximity average

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

What I have is an array of numpy arrays (a 2d numpy array).

```
    my_array = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
        [2, 3, 4, 5]
        [2, 3, 4, 5]
    ]
```

and I want to turn it into:

```
    proximity = 2 
    my_array = [ 
        [1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5]
        [1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5]
        [2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5]
        [2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5]
    ]
```

I have this bit of code:

```
    proximity = 2
    for i in range(0, len(my_array), proximity):
        for j in range(0, len(my_array), proximity):
            ii = i + proximity 
            jj = j + proximity 
            my_array[i:ii, j:jj] = np.average(my_array[i:ii, j:jj])
```

Now my current solution does the trick, but I want to know the pure numpy solution, one without the 2 'for' loops that I use.

Edit: each dimension is divisible by proximity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that each dimension is divisible by `proximity`, you can reshape:

```
(my_array.reshape(rows//proximity, proximity, cols//proximity, proximity)
   .mean(axis=(1,3))           # mean along proximity axes
   .repeat(proximity, axis=0)  # repeat vertically
   .repeat(proximity, axis=1)  # repeat horizontally
)
```

Output:

```
array([[1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5],
       [1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5],
       [2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5]])
```

Another input:

```
my_array = np.array([
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2.5,  2.5,  4.5,  4.5],
       [ 2.5,  2.5,  4.5,  4.5],
       [10.5, 10.5, 12.5, 12.5],
       [10.5, 10.5, 12.5, 12.5],
       [18.5, 18.5, 20.5, 20.5],
       [18.5, 18.5, 20.5, 20.5]])
```

Comment: Very nice answer, was wondering if 
.mean(axis=(1,3)) is same as .mean(1).mean(2)? (I'm new to this Numpy thing, so was wondering if I understand this part)

Comment: Yes. That’s is correct

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's aimed for a square matrix, reshaping the array into square sub-matrices and replicating their means to their initial shape:

```
my_array = my_array.reshape(-1, 2, 2).mean(-1).repeat((2, 2), axis=-1)
print(my_array)
```

---

```
[[1.5 1.5 3.5 3.5]
 [1.5 1.5 3.5 3.5]
 [2.5 2.5 4.5 4.5]
 [2.5 2.5 4.5 4.5]]
```